# TypeError: component.setDisabled is not a function [FIXED IN THE COMMENTS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord, bots

Trying to disable the buttons of a message in **discord.js 14** when I press one of them and is not working. I get this error: **TypeError: component.setDisabled is not a function**

**CODE:**

```js
module.exports = 
{
    id: "paper",
    async execute(interaction) 
    {        
        for (let row of interaction.message.components) 
        {
            for (let component of row.components) 
            {
                if (component.type === 2 && (
                    component.customId === "rock" ||
                    component.customId === "paper" ||
                    component.customId === "scissors"
                )) 
                {
                    console.log(component.customId);
                    component.setDisabled(true);
                }
            }
        }

        await interaction.message.edit({ components: interaction.message.components });

        await interaction.reply("Tried to disable the message");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a Rock Paper Scissors SHOOT game with a discord bot and some buttons I put in the message. What I am expecting is to disable all the buttons of the message when I press one of them. (I'm pretty sure that it's only that error that is not working because the interaction replies correctly messages and the `customId` prints correctly.

Comment: Are you sure about `interaction.message.components[0].components[0]`?

Comment: I found the way to fix it by using `button.data.disabled = true`.